# Populating a Datatable from Memory Stream/Files in .NET

Tags: asp.net, datatable

I have a collection of `.dat` and '.txt' files. The requirement is to load them into DataTable for further processing.

Is there any predefined methods available in .NET ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the link [protobuf-net-data](https://github.com/rdingwall/protobuf-net-data)
There is a simple method defined in there to load the datatable from flat files.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (Stream stream = File.OpenRead("C:\foo.dat"))
using (IDataReader reader = DataSerializer.Deserialize(stream))
{
    dt.Load(reader);
}
```

Note : I haven't tested the library and not aware of performance as well.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to load CSV or delimited text files into data tables in .NET just using the BCL, but it's not that flexible:

```cs
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection conn;
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter da;
string folder=@"D\temp\";
string file="test.csv";
conn = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(@"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + folder + ";Extensions=asc,csv,tab,txt;Persist Security Info=False");
da = new System.Data.Odbc.OdbcDataAdapter("select * from [" + file + "]", conn);
da.Fill(dt);
```

You might have more luck if you check out the following libraries which specialize in CSV/delimited text files:

- http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/
- http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/